AWS GLUE python shell with PostgreSQL
I wanted to create AWS GLUE job with Python Shell.
in my py script I have import
from pg import DB

I wanted to import lib from s3 using
--extra-py-files=s3://${var.glue_bucket}/scripts/PyGreSQL-5.2.3-cp39-cp39-win32.whl

but I'm getting error

is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I use python 3.9 with glue 4

from the name, it seems it is a Win32 wheel. Glue runs on Linux

@Marat how can I get linux whl file?

To address the immediate question, It seems that this package only has pre-built wheels for Windows. You can try passing a source package or building a linux wheel yourself, but probably what you actually want to do is --additional-python-modules PyGreSQL==6.01

I tried additional-python-modules but it doesn't work for glue ver 4

Have you tried the source package then?

@Marat you mean to add source package tar.gz file to extra-py-files?

You might need to look for the binaries. In a similar problem, I had to include psycopg-binary to fix the problem.
